# AngularJS and input datetimelocal default format

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS (1.5) application and have a HTML input with the type `datetime-local`. I'm trying to set the default value with `Date.now()` and would like it to be displayed in the format `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'`. I don't want the seconds displayed. I tried setting the default value in the component and set input value:

```
var todayDate = Date.now();      
this.sampleDate = { value: new Date(todayDate) };
```

In HTML, I set the ng-model set to: `ng-model="$ctrl.sampleDate.value"`

Resulting in date and time and seconds. I have tried adding `.toLocalString()` to `Date.now()` but that did not help. I have also tried adding a filter in the value in the HTML.

Comment: please show the html view where the ng-model is set

Comment: <input type="datetime-local" name="startDateInput" class="form-control" required ng-model="$ctrl.sampleDate.value"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seconds (and milliseconds) won't be shown if they are set to`0`.

You can achieve this by manually setting the seconds and milliseconds to `0`

```
var todayDate = new Date();   
todayDate.setSeconds(0);
todayDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Or by creating a new date without specifying the seconds and milliseconds.

```
var todayDate = new Date(2018, 11, 28, 14, 57)
```

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []).controller('testController', function($scope) {
    var todayDate = new Date();   
    todayDate.setSeconds(0)
    todayDate.setMilliseconds(0)
    $scope.sampleDate = {value: todayDate};
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
   <input ng-model="sampleDate.value" type="datetime-local">
</div>
```

Comment: @Maak--tried what you had suggested but got the error: "setSeconds is not a function". Switched my JS reference to what you had and got the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Notice that I am initializing `todayDate` with `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help @Maak!